# Java Android - Custom Adapter getCount Method nullPointer Error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, baseadapter, custom-adapter

I'm coding a custom adapter for a `ListView` that extends the base adapter. Basically, it will list some names, surnames etc.

`getSize()` method in the adapter class is getting a `NullPointerException`.
I can't figure out what's happening.

```
2021-11-27 13:55:36.561 27997-27997/com.example.listviewlesson E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.listviewlesson, PID: 27997
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listviewlesson/com.example.listviewlesson.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.listviewlesson.UserListAdapter.getCount(**UserListAdapter.java:27**)
        at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:575)
        at com.example.listviewlesson.MainActivity.fillList(**MainActivity.java:26**)
        at com.example.listviewlesson.MainActivity.onCreate(**MainActivity.java:21**)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
```

This is my adapter class

```
package com.example.listviewlesson;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<UserModel> uList;

public UserListAdapter(List<UserModel> list, Context context) {
    this.uList = list;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return uList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return uList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);

    TextView name = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.namexml);
    TextView surname = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.surnamexml);
    TextView age = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.agexml);
    TextView team = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.teamxml);

    name.setText(uList.get(position).getName());
    surname.setText(uList.get(position).getSurname());
    age.setText(uList.get(position).getAge());
    team.setText(uList.get(position).getTeam());

    return layout;
}
}
```

And this is main activity

```
package com.example.listviewlesson;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<UserModel> userList;
UserListAdapter adp;
ListView lview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Tanimla();
    fillList();

}
public void fillList() {
    userList = new ArrayList<UserModel>(userList);
    UserModel model0 = new UserModel("USER1", "SRNAME", "29", "BJK");
    UserModel model1 = new UserModel("USER2", "SRNAME", "29", "BJK");
    UserModel model2 = new UserModel("USER3", "SRNAME", "1", "BJK");

    userList.add(model0);
    userList.add(model1);
    userList.add(model2);


    adp = new UserListAdapter(userList, this);
    lview.setAdapter(adp);
}
void Tanimla() {
    lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview0);
}


}
```

This is main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview0"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is okay just change this line of code in `fillList()` method.

```
 public void fillList() {
    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    UserModel model0 = new UserModel("USER1", "SRNAME", "29", "BJK");
    UserModel model1 = new UserModel("USER2", "SRNAME", "29", "BJK");
    UserModel model2 = new UserModel("USER3", "SRNAME", "1", "BJK");

    userList.add(model0);
    userList.add(model1);
    userList.add(model2);


    adp = new UserListAdapter(userList, this);
    lview.setAdapter(adp);
}
```